# What is time complexity of this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o, time-complexity

Suppose we have an array `w`, that contains `n` integers. By the following definition, and the following pseudo code, please, tell me what is the time complexity of the algorithm w.r.t. `n`:

```
idx[i] = max(j) : 1 <= j < i and w[j] < w[i]

alg:
Data: w : array of integers - idx: a pointer to maximum index with the less value.
Date: w is 1based

idx[1] = -1
for i=: 2 to n do
  j=i-1
  while w[j] > w[i] and j <> -1
  {
    j = idx[j]
  }
  idx[i] =j
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 loops here -

1. First loop `for loop` runs n times. hence its O(n).
2. Second loop `while loop` runs each time from `(i-1) + (i-2) + (i-3) + .... + (i-n)`. it runs for (n-1) times. So O(n).

Combines to `O(n^2)` algo. The other operations are either constant time or O(n) time, hence neglected.